# Rich Text Format in RDLC Tablix

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I need to display rich text format in RDLC Tablix. I have a column in table which is used to record in the format of HTML from UI application. I need to display the same in the RDLC report (Tablix), not in text box.

*Is it possible?*

Comment: please share sample data!

Comment: Can you create a placeholder in that column and in the properties, select `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles`. See if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. It is worked for me. thanks